# react-native-render-html FontFamily attribute not working

Tags: html, react-native, fonts, react-native-render-html

Today I try to use this library to render raw html in my React Native app. Here my code:

```
import HTML from "react-native-render-html";
const htmlContent = `
<div class="page" title="Page 5">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<p><span style="font-size: 11.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT';">Ch&acirc;́t X (C</span><span style="font-size: 7.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT'; vertical-align: -1.000000pt;">x</span><span style="font-size: 11.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT';">H</span><span style="font-size: 7.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT'; vertical-align: -1.000000pt;">y</span><span style="font-size: 11.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT';">O</span><span style="font-size: 7.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT'; vertical-align: -1.000000pt;">4</span><span style="font-size: 11.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT';">N</span><span style="font-size: 7.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT'; vertical-align: -1.000000pt;">2</span><span style="font-size: 11.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT';">) là mu&ocirc;́i amoni của axit cacboxylic đa chức; ch&acirc;́t Y (C</span><span style="font-size: 7.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT'; vertical-align: -1.000000pt;">m</span><span style="font-size: 11.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT';">H</span><span style="font-size: 7.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT'; vertical-align: -1.000000pt;">n</span><span style="font-size: 11.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT';">O</span><span style="font-size: 7.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT'; vertical-align: -1.000000pt;">2</span><span style="font-size: 11.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT';">N</span><span style="font-size: 7.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT'; vertical-align: -1.000000pt;">2</span><span style="font-size: 11.000000pt; font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT';">) là mu&ocirc;́i amoni của một amino axit. Cho m gam E g&ocirc;̀m X và Y (có tỉ lệ mol tương ứng là 3 : 5) tác dụng h&ecirc;́t với lượng dư dung dịch NaOH đun nóng, thu được 4,928 lít (đktc) h&ocirc;̃n hợp khí (g&ocirc;̀m 2 ch&acirc;́t hữu cơ là đ&ocirc;̀ng đẳng liên ti&ecirc;́p) có tỉ kh&ocirc;́i so với hiđro bằng 383/22 và 19,14 gam h&ocirc;̃n hợp mu&ocirc;́i. Ph&acirc;̀n trăm kh&ocirc;́i lượng của Y trong E là </span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
`;

const App = () => {

  return (

    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <HTML
        html={htmlContent} tagsStyles={{
          span: { fontFamily: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT', color:'red' }
        }}
        imagesMaxWidth={Dimensions.get("window").width}
      />
    </ScrollView>
    // <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'TimesNewRomanPSMT', fontSize: 44 }}>affdf</Text>

  );
};
```

I downloaded the font and linked it successfully. The `Text` below already rendered successfully. However  in HTML tag  it still not render. It only renders the `color` and `fontStyle` attribute. Could anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 16):

You need to set the [systemFonts](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/api/trenderengineconfig#systemfonts) Prop:

```
import RenderHtml, { defaultSystemFonts } from 'react-native-render-html';
const systemFonts = [...defaultSystemFonts, 'Montserrat-Regular', 'Montserrat-Bold'];
<RenderHtml 
  contentWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
  source={{ html: htmlSource }} 
  tagsStyles={{a: {color:'#58585A',textDecorationLine:'none', fontSize:16, fontFamily:'Montserrat-Bold',lineHeight: 23},p:{**fontFamily:'Montserrat-Regular**',lineHeight: 23,color:'#58585A',fontSize:16,marginBottom:16}, img:{display: 'none'}}} 
  systemFonts={systemFonts}
                  />
```

It's important to set the systemFonts Prop in RenderHtml component and make sure you have react-native-render-html v:6.0.0 >

Check their documentation about this [systemFonts](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/api/trenderengineconfig#systemfonts) Prop

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the [`systemFonts`](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/api/trenderengineconfig#systemfonts) Prop:

```
<RenderHTML systemFonts={['IRANSansX-Bold']} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your example in an Expo snack here: https://snack.expo.io/@jsamr/stack-overflow-63626884

If you take a look a the Web renderer on the right, you'll notice that the appropriate font is displayed (in this example, monospace). Are you sure you configured the font appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

file.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Pressable, Image } from 'react-native';
import RenderHtml , { defaultSystemFonts } from 'react-native-render-html';

const CustomComponent = (props) => {
const { width } = Dimensions.get('screen')
const systemFonts = [...defaultSystemFonts, global.fontRegular];
return (
        <>
                   {props.recepie?.data.description &&
                        <RenderHtml
                            contentWidth={width - 30}
                            source={{ html: `<html><body> 
                           <p>${props.recepie?.data.description}</p></body> 
                             </html>` }}
                            tagsStyles={mixedStyle}
                            systemFonts={systemFonts}
                        />}
        </>
    );
};
const mixedStyle = {
    body: {
        fontFamily: 'your global font name',
        color: '#212121'
    },
    p: {
        fontFamily: 'your global font name',
    }
}
export default CustomComponent ;
```